# How to set parameters for SaveAs() dialog in Word.Application?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I want to save a Word document as PDF from a PowerShell script.
The following code works for me.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\TEMP\WORD.DOCX")
$Name = ($Doc.Fullname).Replace("DOCX", "PDF")
$result = $Doc.SaveAs([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)
$Doc.Close()
echo "Saved to $Name"
```

The produced PDF is a PDF/A though.

When I save the document manually then I can set the option "PDF/A compliant" in a dialog which pops up.

How can I change this format specific option via PowerShell?
The pictures explain perhaps better what I'm trying.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried recording the action?

Comment: No, how would I do that? Sounds interesting.

Comment: Which dialog box? Show a screen shot, perhaps? *Some* parameters of the Save As dialog box can be set, but I don't recall this even being in *that* dialog box...

Comment: Launch Word, start recording a macro, do the thing, then stop recording the macro and look at the resulting code.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The recorded macros look exactly the same. There is no difference in saving with "PDF/A compliant" checked or unchecked.

Comment: Then I don't think VBScript/VBA can do what you want.

Comment: This is not VB, it's Powershell.

Comment: I added some pictures to show what I'm trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of is by using the [ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat) function instead of `SaveAs`.

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Doc  = $Word.Documents.Open("C:\TEMP\WORD.DOCX")
$Name = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($Doc.Fullname, "PDF")

# Use ExportAsFixedFormat function.
# See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat

# Parameters:
# OutputFileName, ExportFormat, OpenAfterExport, OptimizeFor, Range, From
# To, Item, IncludeDocProps, KeepIRM, CreateBookmarks, DocStructureTags
# BitmapMissingFonts, UseISO19005_1

# The last parameter 'UseISO19005_1' saves as PDF/A Compliant
$result = $Doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
               $Name,
               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat]::wdExportFormatPDF,
               $false,
               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor]::wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen,
               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange]::wdExportAllDocument,
               0,
               0,
               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem]::wdExportDocumentContent,
               $true,
               $true,
               [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks]::wdExportCreateWordBookmarks,
               $true,
               $false,
               $true
          )    

$Doc.Close()

# clean up Com object after use
$Word.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```