What is the option in .NET that matches the "Optimize for" option when saving a Word document as a PDF?
In Microsoft Word, when you go to save a file as a PDF, you can click more options and pull up this option to "Optimize for: Minimize size (publishing online)".

How do I find this option in .NET for a PowerShell script? I am looking for documentation on how to find this option for a PowerShell script. I found WdExportOptimizeFor but it does not result in optimized PDFs the same way.
param (
  [string]$source = $(Throw "You have to specify a source path."),
  [string]$file_type = "rtf"
)

$suffix_length = 3
if ($source.EndsWith("docx")) {
  $suffix_length = 4
}

$destiny = $source.Substring(0, $source.Length - $suffix_length) + "pdf"
$saveaspath = [ref] $destiny 
$formatPDF = [ref] 17 # 17 = PDF

$word = new-object -ComObject "word.application"
$doc = $word.documents.open($source)
$doc.ExportAsFixedFormat($saveaspath, $formatPDF, $false, $wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen)
$doc.Close()

echo "Converted file: $source"

ps winword | kill


Perhaps wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen Needs to be set to 1 (the value for print is 0). Or you can try to get the value using the syntax in, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502233/how-to-set-parameters-for-saveas-dialog-in-word-application , but I'm not sure you can do that in powershell any more.
